# Characteristic Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the linear factors for $x^3-6x^2-22$ ?
I tried  :
By using rational root theorem,
If $p/q$ is a rational root of $f(x)=x^3-6x^2-22$
Then we get $p/q$ is $\{+1,-1,+22,-22,+2,-2,-11,+11\}$

Comment: This polynomial has no rational roots. But, since the title of your question is “Characteristic Polynomials”, I suspect that you got this polynomial from another problem Which problem is that?

Answer (score 2):

By Eisenstein the polynomial $x^3-6x^2-22$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, so there is no rational root. This can be seen directly by testing the possible values with the rational root theorem. So there are no linear factors over $\Bbb Q$. By the mean value theorem, there is a real root, so there is a linear factor over $\Bbb R$. Over $\Bbb C$ the polynomial decomposes into three linear factors.